# Создание текстового редактора на С# windows form.Не создается новый документ в текстовом редакторе. Не при выборе кнопки в меню не быстрыми клавишами

Tags: c#, winforms, shortcuts, текстовый-редактор

[image]
В общем , это практическая в которой у меня должны срабатывать быстрые клавиши ,но не только ctrl+N не срабатывает , оно в общем не хочет создавать новый док.

```
private void mnuNew_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
blank frm = new blank();
frm.MdiParent = this;
frm.Show();
}
```

Код ошибку тоже не выдает. Не могу понять в чем проблема(
подскажите пути решения , знаний маловато пока что.

Comment: В окне Solution Explorer  Add/
Add Windows Form… . В появившемся окне называем форму – blank.cs.
Создается дочерняя форма.Новые документы будут у
нас появляться при нажатии пункта меню New (которому мы установили сочетание
клавиш Ctrl+N), поэтому дважды щелкаем в этом пункте и переходим в код который я написала выше.

Comment: как конкретно и где вы связали горячие клавиши с командами меню?

Comment: [MenuItem.Shortcut Свойство](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.menuitem.shortcut?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Начала понимать свою ошибку, спасибо что  натолкнули на ответ

Comment: System.ArgumentException: "Форма, указанная как MdiParent для данной формы, не является MdiContainer. Arg_ParamName_Name"

Comment: по итогу при нажатии быстрых клавиш,на мой код выходит это сообщение

Comment: ну то есть быстрые клавиши заработали и теперь у вас совершенно другая проблема, не связанная с этим вопросом, так?

Comment: ну и читайте текст ошибки, там же все написано

Comment: Факт, спасибо что надоумили. Теперь я знаю больше.